# Problem cooking textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, game-engine, texture-baking

Could someone help me understand how I could get the same texture rendering on a game engine like second life as on blender?
To be clear, some people manage to simply baking the textures and get the same quality, with the brightness, shadows, reflections, nothing moves.
But when I do it the same way, the quality is sabotaged and the textures become blurred.

Comment: This is a very broad topic. Please add images and detailed informations about your workflow and the outcome (for example, what exactly is "the same way").

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.